# Incorrect mapping of texture in opengl

Tags: c++, opengl

When I want to map a png file to a rectangle, but the texture seems break into two pieces. Here is the vertices and indices and part of the code related to the texture.

```
    program pro("vertex.vs", "fragment.fs");

unsigned int VAO;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);

// triangle
float vertices[] = {
    // positions          // colors           // texture coords
    0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, // top right
    0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, // bottom right
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, // bottom left
    -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f // top left
};
unsigned int indices[] = {
    0, 1, 3,// first triangle
    1, 2, 3 // second triangle
};

unsigned int VBO, EBO;
glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);
glBindVertexArray(VAO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)(6 * sizeof(float)));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);

unsigned int texture;
glGenTextures(1, &texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

int width, height, nrChannels;
stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(true);

unsigned char* data = stbi_load("图片22.jpg", &width, &height, &nrChannels, 0);
if (data) {
    std::cout<<width<<" "<<height<<" "<<nrChannels<<std::endl;
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
} else {
    std::cout << "Failed to load texture" << std::endl;
}
stbi_image_free(data);

pro.use();
pro.setInt("ourTexture", 0);
```

And this is the result of the texture. [running result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AlUm.png)
It seems that the bottom left and bottom right part are correct but the top left and right parts are inverse.
However, when I tried another picture whose size is 512*512, it can be correctly displayed. [the normal one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNn34.png)

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.  And my English is so poor that maybe I missed some information.

It is solved by add the code

```
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
```

because the height and width are not multiples of 4.

Comment: Your code seems fine. It's working for me.

Comment: If you unpack alignment it works.